# how can angular6 eager load tab content

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I am using angular 6 material tab component, and I found the tab contents are loaded laziy.
Are there any way  I can make it eager load instead of lazy load?
The reason is I need to use third party plugin, but if for lazy load, the content is null, and actual dimension is not accurately detected. So the third party can not be displayed accurately.
I remember this is configurable, but can not find way to do it.

some thing like:

```
<mat-tab-group [lazy]=false >
    <mat-tab label="xxx">
        content
    </mat-tab>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading):

> By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them into the DOM until the tab is activated.

So there is no action needed to eager load the contents.

In case this is still not enough for your use case, you may want to use a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) or one of the available [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).